# Calculation the Sum of a row in Access

Tags: ms-access

I have a new database and it has a variety of costings by client. Essentially it has multiple field per row that can have differing prices.

I don't know why but I am struggling to have a field calculate these into a total.

It looks a little like this

I.D. - 1£ - 2£ - 3£ - 4£ (*There are fifteen of these in total*)

I tried doing a simple sum * ([1£]+[2£]) * and this said there was an issue because I hadn't specified the ID.

I know I used to do sums this way, such as calculating the difference between two dates in a row.

Could someone advise me please?

Thanks in advance

Nic

Comment: Could you please show us the Query you are using?

Comment: Can you provide some sample data? I am getting confused on whether you are actually including an ID or not, and what kind of schema we are working with.

Comment: Are `[1£]` and `[2£]` field names or values contained in fields?

Comment: They are the field names, the format of the fields is currency though. So as they can have a variety of costs listed, I simply named them 1-15 and put the pound sign as part of the field name for reference.  Essentially, I need a total of all of these fields to be calculated automatically in a field I can have on the same form that the costs are input onto.  Thank you

Comment: Is that calculation to be performed in a query, by the Control Source for a form or report field, or directly in the table?

Comment: I have struggled to paste anything, but I will see if I can type something that might make sense!

Comment: ID - [1£] - [2£] - [3£]<br/> 1  -  £22.00  - £32.00  -  £7.50 <br/> So I would need a field to calculate the values of the three fields for a total amount.  The ID is simply just the PK for the record. <br/> Sorry if the formatting of this post isnt helpful!